# Высота элемента RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Возможно ли сделать высоту элемента таким образом, чтобы он был до самого низа экрана? То есть верхом он цепляется как `android:layout_below="@id/someID"` а снизу к низу экрана, в зависимости от высоты самого экрана телефона?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_below="@id/someID"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ConstraintLayout. С этим контейнером очень легко растянуть как его самого с помощью `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"` так и любой виджет:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Выше пример контейнера с textView на весь экран телефона. `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` - указывает куда "прилипнуть". А `android:layout_width="0dp"` говорит заполнить все пространство.